# Seek function not working on flowplayer

Tags: flowplayer

I want a video to start at a specific point (say 30 seconds into it) and I have tried using the seek() function of flowplayer, according to the API documentation .

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) {

  api.bind("ready", function () {
    seek(30);

  });

});
```

But I get the following error message on the console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: seek is not defined

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use the HTML5 player or flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like you are calling the `seek` method in the correct way.  When you `bind` to the `ready` event it gives you a couple of parameters.  The first argument is the jQuery event object and the second provides a handle on the player API.

From the api parameter you should then be able to call `seek`

**Example**

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) {

    api.bind("ready", function (e, api) {
        api.seek(30);
    });
});
```

For more info see [flowplayer api docs](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had somehow failed to notice this.